# Amazon RDS: Restore cluster snapshot no db instance

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm getting problems restoring AWS RDS cluster snapshot.

My snapshots are generating automatically from AWS via console config. Now I'm trying restore those snapshots via AWS RDS API for Ruby. I use `restore_db_cluster_from_snapshot` function and I restore cluster successfully but this new cluster haven't any db instance attached.

I can't generate `db_snapshot` because my db it's on cluster, I only have `db_cluster_snapshot`. Because this I can't use `restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot` function.

Simply example of working code:

```
db_cluster = @rds.restore_db_cluster_from_snapshot({
                                                    db_cluster_identifier: 'restored-from-rake',
                                                    snapshot_identifier: '',
                                                    engine: snapshot_data.engine,
                                                    database_name: 'restored-from-rake-db'
                                                  })
```

Any idea about this?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restoring an Aurora (cluster) snapshot involves 2 steps:

1. Restore the cluster snapshot to an Aurora cluster, then
2. Add RDS instances to your cluster.

So, once you've restored your RDS cluster, follow that with a call to `@rds.create_db_instance()`:

```
db_instances = @rds.create_db_instance({ 
    db_cluster_identifier: 'restored-from-rake', 
    ... 
})
```

Comment: After several tests I imagined it to be so, but my question is about snapshots. I do not want to create a new instance from scratch, I want load the snapshot of my actual instance. Is there any way to do this or am I wrong?

My scenario:

db_instance = auroratest
db_cluster = auroratest-cluster
db_cluster_snapshot = my_cluster_snapshot

I can't create db_snapshot because instance it's on cluster yet.

How can I create/attach one copy (or snapshot) of my db_instance "auroratest" to restored cluster?

Comment: Aurora does not have single instances. Aurora uses a cluster sitting behind an instance. You cannot have an instance without a cluster. When you restore a cluster from a snapshot, that's like restoring a MySQL instance from a snapshot. But a restored cluster does not have any instances, so you need to add instances to your cluster. Again, the data is in the cluster, not the instance for Aurora.

Answer (score 0):

This action only restores the DB cluster, not the DB instances for that DB cluster. You must invoke the `CreateDBInstance` action to create DB instances for the restored DB cluster, specifying the identifier of the restored DB cluster in `DBClusterIdentifier` . You can create DB instances only after the `RestoreDBClusterFromSnapshot` action has completed and the DB cluster is available.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot.html#description